# ¿Cómo regresar a la página anterior al grabar un formulario django?

Tags: django

No logro encontrar la forma de regresar a la página anterior después de grabar un formulario.

Utilizando POST era fácil ya que solo era cuestión de utilizar
`HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))`

Pero utilizando generic.UpdateView no logro hacerlo ...

La clase form que construye el formulario tiene dos botones, el submit y cancel que **SI FUNCIONA** y regresa a la página anterior, 
pero el botón de grabar utiliza `get_success_url` si está definida o `get_absolute_url` por defecto.

En mi template utilizo el tag `{% crispy form %}` y el resto del código es el siguiente:

```
class ComunicacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ComunicacionModel
        fields = ['tipo', 'texto', 'active']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = helper.FormHelper()

        # creamos layouts
        self.helper.layout = layout.Layout()        

        # agregamos todos los campos
        for fld in self.Meta.fields:
            self.helper.layout.append(fld)

        # agregamos los botones de acción
        bSave = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-split"><span class="icon text-white-50"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></span><span class="text">Grabar</span></button>'
        bCancel = '<a class="btn btn-warning btn-icon-split" style="margin-left: 5px" href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}"><span class="icon text-white-50"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></span><span class="text">Cancela</span></a>'
        self.helper.layout.append(layout.HTML("<hr>"))
        self.helper.layout.append(layout.HTML(bSave))
        self.helper.layout.append(layout.HTML(bCancel))


class Comunicacion(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # en esta posición no puedo obtener HTTP_REFERER
        return reverse('%s:detail' % self._meta.model_name, args=(self.pk,))


class ComunicacionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ComunicacionModel
    form_class = ComunicacionForm
    template_name = 'comunes/formulario.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['previous_url'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')     # aquí la obtengo correctamente
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        # en esta posición no puedo obtener HTTP_REFERER
        # referer = self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        # if referer:
        #     return referer
        return reverse_lazy('{app}:list'.format(app=self.model._meta.verbose_name.lower()))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Intenta revisar este post, se indica como redireccionar al sitio anterior luego de hacer un llamado POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request/35796330)

Comment: Gracias William, el problema es que no sirve para el mecanismo de Crispy Form, tendré que cambiar la forma de usar el armado automático de formulario ...

Answer (score 0):

La forma que encontré de hacerlo es agregando un campo oculto al formulario
con la referencia a la página de donde vengo.

Lo agrego por jscript para no tener que modificar el **FormHelper**

Abajo dejo los cambios haciendo referencia al código que envié en el primer mensaje.

```
<script>
$('#myform').append('<input type="hidden" name="previous_url" value="'+document.referrer+'" />');
</script>
```

```
class ComunicacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        ...
        self.helper = helper.FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = "myform"  # DEFINO EL NOMBRE DEL FORMULARIO
        ...


class ComunicacionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ...

    # descarto get_context_data
    # descarto get_success_url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        referer = self.request._post['previous_url']
        if referer:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(referer)
        return response
```